# How to create a standard spreadsheet file programmatically without using LibXL?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, xls

I want to create standard spreadsheet files in objective-C  which can be opened in ipad too, without using paid libraries such as LibXL.

I already created HTML tables and simply created a `.xls` file by using following code( `string1` contains HTML table ) :

```
NSURL * documentPath = [NSFileManager.defaultManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask].lastObject;    
NSURL *filePath1 = [documentPath URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"FileName.xls"];

[string1 writeToFile:filePath1.path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

This file opens  in MS Excel without problem but unable to open in ipad. What is the solution for it then ?

Comment: Please rearrange your words a bit, add few more to get a better idea.

Comment: please again check question ...

Comment: A simple solution would be to save the file in CSV format which can be read by both numbers and excel. You lose out on formatting in this method however. The other answer is to use a library like LibXL as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: @RASS I strongly  want proper formatting . And for LibXL I have to buy it more than $190.

Comment: @RASS you are saying to make the CSV file. Do you know standard method to create CSV file .. please suggest to this newbee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK CSV is very simple. It stands for Comma Separated Values and is exactly that.

For example if you want a table of people with the columns Name, Date you would do something like this:

```
NSMutableString *csvString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Name,Date\n"];//The \n character means new row
for (Person *p in array) {
    //This is an arbitrary class / array
    [csvString appendFormat:@"%@,%@\n", p.name, p.date]
}

NSString *path = //File path ending in myFile.csv
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = [str writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"File written successfully to path: %@", path);
}
```

This file can be read by most number crunching applications e.t.c but lacks formatting.

Comment: what if cell I want to add already has comma separated entity which I want in single cell?? For Example.. I want Tiger,Lion,Elephant these three comma separated words in on cell.

Comment: You can surround these in "Tiger,Lion,Elephant" or 'Tiger,Lion,Elephant' I can't quite remember which but it is possible. You'll have to experiment with that. The easiest way to find out all the CSV syntax is to make a complex speadsheet in Numbers and export it to CSV then look at it in Text Edit.